# How are built-in objects (ex: 'Object') created in Javascript by any JS engine?

Tags: javascript, v8, built-in

In Javascript there are many built-in objects (ex: Object,Number,Array,Math)  which are ready to be Cloned/Prototyped to create our own custom objects.

I understand how the custom objects inherit built-in objects. 'Object' object is on top of the inheritance chain.

How is this 'Object' object created in memory in the first place? Who creates it?

Can anyone please explain this with example of any JS engine? (V8 engine preferably). Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: `Object` is a function. It's not top of the inheritance chain. The relevant part of the spec that explains how to initialize the realm is http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-createrealm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript engine creates the 'Object' object.  To be specific, 'Object' is a function in turn it is an object since functions are first-class object in javascript.

If you want to check the source code of built-ins, below is the V8 engine open-source repository in Github.

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-object.cc